# Problems with the size of inputs, java noob

Tags: java

```
import java.lang.StringBuffer;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter number to be reversed: ");
      int x = scan.nextInt();
      Integer number = new Integer(x);
      String reverse = new String();

      for(int i = 0; i <= number.toString().length()-1; i++) {
         reverse = new StringBuffer(reverse).insert(i, number.toString().charAt(number.toString().length()-(1+i))).toString();
      }

      System.out.println(reverse);
   }
}
```

I have this code, the problem is that any imput over 9 digits will raise an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "4444444444"
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at test.main(test.java:9)
```

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: Thanks everyone, your help was invaluable and the issue is now resolved. supprised at how fast the responces were cheers

Comment: If your issue was resolved **upvote** the helpful answers **by clicking the up arrow** next to them, and **accept** the answer that best resolved your question **by clicking the check mark** next to it.

Comment: please click the green check-mark beside the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of int and Integer use long and Long. int only goes up to 2,147,483,647

**update:**
Looking at your code again, Why are you puling in ints when you're using it as a String.

Use char for each character, print an error if they enter a non-numeric. This way they can enter as long a number as they please.

Answer (score 3):

An `int` can hold numbers within the following range:

-2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647

User `long` instead of `int` and use `scan.nextLong();` to get the input.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you use Long, you'll still be able to type a number that's just too long. Do this:

```
int x;
boolean isNumberGood = false;
try { 
  x = Scanner.nextInt();
  isNumberGood = true;
} catch (java.util.InputMismatchException ex) {
  System.out.println("bad number!");
}
```

and don't proceed if isNumberGood isn't true